# Compiling and linking files on different directories in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, fortran

I am working on a fortran project with many files and libraries. To organize information I created within the working directory three subfolders, call them /code, /obj and /bin.

How can I write a shell script so that I can invoke

```
gfortran -c $(code)/file1.f90 $(code)/file2.f90 $(code)/file3.f90

gfortran -c -J/$(obj) $(bin)/binary $(obj)/file1.o $(obj)/file2.o $(obj)/file3.o
```

I know it is a very stupid question but I am not familiar with shell scripting or 'make'. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Have you tried a web search for "GNU Make tutorial"?  The first hit has the title "GNU Make in Detail for Beginners".

Comment: No. But thanks for the suggestion